# MMC reader won't automount in 18.04

Tags: mount, sd-card, mmc

My SD-cards won't mount automatically anymore. In the past it did, also on Ubuntu 18.04, but now when returning from my summer holiday and upgraded the system it won't anymore.

Anyone knows a trick? Now i need to open «Disks» (gnome-disks?) and then manually mount each partition on the card, or with `sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0pX /mount/destination`. It's more convenient when it's mounted automatically.